# WCF to WebLogic communication

Tags: wcf, weblogic, wcf-security

I'm trying to talk to this service here:
https://dmrsit1gateway1.skat.dk/B2B/USImportoer/Service?WSDL

It's a Oracle Weblogic service using x509 certificates.

Whenever I send a request I receive a SecurityAccessDeniedException with the additional info:
***{"Failed to derive subject from token.javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: javax.security.auth.callback.UnsupportedCallbackException: Unsupported callback class: NameCallback javax.security.auth.callback.NameCallback@15d38692"}***

Somehow my requests does not seem to conform with what's expected.

This is my latest attempt:

```
var binding = new CustomBinding();
var sec = (AsymmetricSecurityBindingElement)SecurityBindingElement.CreateMutualCertificateBindingElement(MessageSecurityVersion.WSSecurity10WSTrustFebruary2005WSSecureConversationFebruary2005WSSecurityPolicy11BasicSecurityProfile10);

var x509token = new X509SecurityTokenParameters();
sec.EnableUnsecuredResponse = true;
sec.EndpointSupportingTokenParameters.Signed.Add(x509token);
sec.IncludeTimestamp = true;
sec.SecurityHeaderLayout = SecurityHeaderLayout.LaxTimestampLast;
sec.AllowInsecureTransport = true;
binding.Elements.Add(sec);

binding.Elements.Add(new TextMessageEncodingBindingElement(MessageVersion.Soap11, Encoding.UTF8));

HttpsTransportBindingElement httpsBindingElement = new HttpsTransportBindingElement();
httpsBindingElement.RequireClientCertificate = true;
binding.Elements.Add(httpsBindingElement);

string endpoint = "https://dmrsit1gateway1.skat.dk:443/B2B/USImportoer/Service?WSDL";

var client = new USImportoerServiceTypeClient(binding, new EndpointAddress(new Uri(endpoint), new DnsEndpointIdentity("REDACTED"), new AddressHeaderCollection()));
client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SetDefaultCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "REDACTED");
client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, "REDACTED");

var response = client.getUSDispensationTypeListeHent(input);
```

Any input how to troubleshoot this would be highly appreciated.